# Summation of TFIDF sparse vector values for each document in Spark with Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, tf-idf, apache-spark-mllib

I calculated the TFIDF for 3 sample text documents using HashingTF and IDF of Pyspark and I got the following SparseVector result:

```
(1048576,[558379],[1.43841036226])
(1048576,[181911,558379,959994],  [0.287682072452,0.287682072452,0.287682072452])
(1048576,[181911,959994],[0.287682072452,0.287682072452])
```

How to calculate the sum of TFIDF values for all terms within a document. 
E.g. (0.287682072452 + 0.287682072452) for the 3d document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output from `IDF` is just a PySpark `SparseVector` when it is exposed to Python and its values are standard NumPy `array` so all you need is `sum` call:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseVector

v = SparseVector(1048576,[181911,959994],[0.287682072452,0.287682072452])
v.values.sum()
## 0.57536414490400001
```

or over RDD:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([
  SparseVector(1048576,[558379],[1.43841036226]),
  SparseVector(1048576, [181911,558379,959994],  
      [0.287682072452,0.287682072452,0.287682072452]),
  SparseVector(1048576,[181911,959994],[0.287682072452,0.287682072452])])

rdd.map(lambda v: v.values.sum())
```

Comment: Thank @zero323, it works well for a given value as in your example but when I convert TFIDFs for all documents as in the follwoing code:

`i=0`
`for k in tfidf.collect():`
   `v[i]=SparseVector(k)`
   `i= i+1`

I get the message:
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SparseVector'

Comment: How is that related to the sum of values in vector? Is there any context here?

Comment: Yes, because my question also says "for each document" not for one row. and the first step in your answer is to use SparseVector method which doesn't work for each document.

Comment: Do you mean `map` (see an edit)? If you want to sum of sum just add `sum()` call at the end.